# Retrieve dynamic html element on click event backbonejs

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm studying Backbonejs. I have a problem with dynamic elements that I add with handlebars.js. This is my HTML snippet:
**HTML**

```
 <section class="single-item">
    {{#each [0]}} {{#if name}}
    <div class="card col s12">
        <form action="/productdetail" id="product-form">
            <div id="dettagliofromhomepage" class="card-image">
                {{#if img}}
                <img id="imgslide" src="{{img}}" data-prod="{{id}}"> {{else}}
                <img id="imgslide" src="img/no.jpg" data-prod="{{id}}"> {{/if}}
            </div>
            <div id="card-border" class="col s12">
                <div class="card-content col s6">
                    <p class="productTitle">{{name}}
                        <br> €{{price}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action col s6 ">
                    <a id="bottone-ca" class="waves-effect waves-light btn light-green darken-3"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/if}} {{/each}}
    </section>
```

I want the anchor "bottone-ca" to output the value of an element of the section "Single item" on click. I.e. I want to retrieve the value of `<p>` in the class "card content". I dynamically add the five elements using the construct "each". However, when I try to use operator "this" on js, I can get as output the first element of the items I add.
This is my JS snippet:

```
define(function(require) {

var $ = require("jquery");
var Backbone = require("backbone");
var Products_homepage = require("models/Products_homepage");
var Products = require("models/Products");
var MyCollection = require("collections/Categories");
var localizzatoreView = require("views/pages/localizzatoreView");
var Utils = require("utils");
var productHomepage = require("models/productHomepage");
var onlineProduct = require("models/onlineProduct");
var saleProduct = require("models/saleProduct");


var MyView = Utils.Page.extend({
    constructorName: "MyView",
    model: Products_homepage,

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = Utils.templates.myview;
    },

    id: "myview",
    className: "i-g page",

    events: {
        "click #imgslide": "prodotto",
        "click #bottone-ca": "carrello"
    },

    render: function() {

        var that = this;

        var online = new onlineProduct();
        var sale2 = new saleProduct();
        var arraytest = [];
        var loca= localStorage.getItem("localizzazione");

        online.fetch({
            success: function() {

                arraytest[0]=(online.attributes);
                test= online.attributes;


                sale2.fetch({
                    success: function() {

                        $(that.el).html(that.template(arraytest));

                        that.startslider();
                        that.startnav();

                        return that;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    },

    carrello: function(e) {
        var arraytemp = [];
        arraytemp = localStorage.getItem("Carrello");

        var idprod = $('#id_prodotto').val(),
        name = $("#name").val(),
        img = $("#img").val(),
        price = $("#price").val(),
        quantity = 1;

        /*Here i want to retrieve element that i clicked */

        var prod = new Products({
            name: name,
            id: idprod,
            img: img,
            price: parseFloat(price).toFixed(2),
            quantity: quantity,
            total: price * quantity
        });

        var Carrello = JSON.parse(localStorage["Carrello"]);
        Carrello.push(prod);
        localStorage["Carrello"] = JSON.stringify(Carrello);

        Backbone.history.navigate("basket", {
            trigger: true
        });

    }
});
```

Sorry in advance for any errors in snippets. I'm new to JavaScript and backbone. Thanks in advance for help. I'm using Stack Overflow as a tool to learn.

Comment: Is your template rending multiple product forms (#product-form) to the page? If so, you will have a lot duplicated element IDs. This is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You always get the first element for global selectors like `$('#id_prodotto')` because you are using `id` selectors. `id` is supposed to be unique in the entire document and browser returns the first match. You should not use static `id`'s in dynamic templates. Use a CSS class or other attributes instead.

That said, you can access the current element via the event object like `$(event.currentTaget);` and query the DOM related to the event target so that it returns the nearest element having the `id`, for example `$(event.currentTaget).closest('#card-border').find('p').text()`.

But it is still advisable to not have multiple elements with same `id`.